# How to model a large catalogue with many different types of products and attributes in PimCore 5+

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

I am an experienced full-stack web dev, but new to PimCore. I’m organising a large catalogue of many types of items in PimCore and have looked through the documentation many times, but I still don’t know how to tackle two basic issues I have organising my product data into classes. I hope some more experienced PimCore users or devs can shine some light on this.

**Issue 1: how to model general product attributes that apply to all products in the catalogue.**

All of the products in my catalogue will have a name and a description, so I thought it made sense to make a Product class that has these fields and make all of my specific product classes subclasses of that Product class so I wouldn’t have to add name and description fields to each subclass individually.

I tried to set this up, but in the object editor of the specific subclass the layout fields that I added to the generic Product superclass don’t show up. Am I missing something here? Should my approach actually work? If not, what would be the PimCore approach to modelling this?

**Issue 2: how best to model products with multiple options, ie. variants over more than one dimension.**

For example, T-shirts with both color and size options (let’s say, 3 colors and 3 sizes for a total of 9 variants). I would want to create one single T-shirt product in the object tree and then add 3 color options and 3 size options for an (automatic) total of 9 variants. I want the T-shirt to appear as a single product in the e-commerce frontend and let the end customer determine the value of both options.

I am wondering if it is at all possible to do this in a way that allows me to specify the 3 color options and the 3 sizes independently of each other. The examples I find in the documentation all show me a fully expanded object tree covering all options (eg., 1 T-shirt object, with 3 subobjects for each size, each with 3 subobjects for each color in that size). Although data inheritance helps with the management of this info, a change in the available colors would still have to be made once for every size option. I can’t imagine there is not a better way to set up object variants in multiple dimensions in PimCore, but days of searching have led me nowhere. Am I missing something here? Or does PimCore actually force you to create objects/variants for every combination of product options? If not, what would be the PimCore approach to modelling this?

I hope someone with a little experience in this field is willing to shed some light on these two issues. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received very helpful answers on the PimCore forums, by user [fash](https://talk.pimcore.org/u/fash):

> **Issue 1:** Pimcore DataObject classes cannot inherit from each other. The way to go would be to create one product class (that
> contains all common product attributes) and then use object bricks or
> classification store groups to model category specific attributes.
>
> Then on object level, the corresponding object brick or classification
> store group can be added to the product object (depending on its
> category or other criteria).
>
> **Issue 2**: As you already noticed, the default way of dealing with different variants of a product is to create an object instance for
> each variant and utilize data inheritance to reduce data maintenance
> effort (like in the demo). Also as Andrew already pointed out, adding
> some helper functionality like a generate variants button is easily
> possible.
>
> The reason why we create a unique data object for each variant most of
> the time is, that normally each SKU has a unique product number and
> also in terms of e-commerce it needs to be possible to reference the
> exact variant that was ordered. As an alternative you of course could
> use data structures like field definitions or block to follow your
> approach and have to attributes (like color, size, etc.) and add
> multiple values to them and then deal on the output channel with the
> variant generation. It is really up to your use case and your system
> what fits better.
>
> An hybrid solution would be to define possible variants with variant
> attributes, and then generate the actual object variants on the fly
> when one is ordered.